# Action of algebraic group in cohomology of equivariant algebraic vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-actions, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a projective algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field. Let an algebraic group $G$ act algebraically on $X$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $G$-equivariant vector bundle (or, more generally, coherent sheaf) on $X$.

**Is it true that the natural action of $G$ on cohomology $H^*(X,\mathcal{F})$ is an algebraic representation?**

Comment: Which cohomology?

Comment: I think I good way of understanding this is by asking a more general question: given a morphism $f:Z\to Y$ of simplicial schemes, given an $\mathcal{O}_Z$-module $\mathcal{E}$, what is the structure of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module on the higher direct images $R^qf_*\mathcal{E}$?  When $Y$ is the simplicial scheme $BG$ of $G$, when $Z$ is the simplicial scheme associated to the action of $G$ on $X$, and when $\mathcal{E}$ is the $\mathcal{O}_Z$-module associated to a $G$-linearization of $\mathcal{F}$, this answers your question.

Comment: Of course you do need a hypothesis for this approach to work, namely that $G$ is flat over the base scheme (which it is, since your base scheme is $\text{Spec}\ k$ for a field $k$), cf. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07TJ  Then the fact that $R^qf_*\mathcal{E}$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module when $\mathcal{E}$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_Z$-module follows from the flat base change theorem.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you very much. I used to think on equivariant sheaves in a more old fashioned way, without simplicial schemes. Is there a good reference to that approach?